# Firebase querySnapshot not updating realtime with where condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud firestore with flutter to store the chat and using where condition to get the chats.
the documents returns correctly but when the new data is added the chat list will not update in realtime.

How the chat is stored:-
collection -> message {message, timestamp, sentBy,sentTo} are the message fields

the query is

```
firestore
        .collection('chats_v2')
        .where('sentBy', isEqualTo: 'abc')
        .where('sentTo', isEqualTo: 'xyz')
        .orderBy('timestamp')
        .snapshots();
```

The Chat loads perfectly for first time, but when the new message is added to collection list wont update

I also tried, this dint work:

```
firestore
        .collection('chats_v2')
        .where('trackId', isEqualTo: trackId)
        .where('groupId', isEqualTo: groupId)
        .orderBy('timestamp')
        .snapshots().listen((data){
          //return the QuerySnapshot from here to StreamBuilder;
        });
```

Comment: Managed to find an [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-fully-functioning-flutter-chat-app-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore-efc98df096b0) that display steps in building a Flutter Chat Application that I would suggest you have a look at. Also, for questions or concerns pertaining to Firebase products and services, I would like to direct you to the [Firebase Support page](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0). As they would be better suited in providing answers to your Firebase inquiries.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you figure this out?