# Firestore query condition using where

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to learn how to query firestore with the where condition.

If I comment out the where condition shown below, the content of the collection loads and is correctly sorted.

I have a document in that collection with an attribute called: "sharing" with a value called "open". I expect it to be the only rendered document in the collection when I uncomment the where condition.

[image]

Instead, I get no values returned. If I remove the where condition - all values are returned and sorted by title.

```
function useImpactMetrics() {
    const [impactMetrics, setImpactMetrics] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("impact_metrics")
        //.where("sharing", "==", "open")
        .orderBy("title")
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          const impactMetrics = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))
          setImpactMetrics(impactMetrics)
        })
    }, [])
    return impactMetrics
  }
```

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514221/firebase-querysnapshot-not-updating-realtime-with-where-condition) and the blog referenced in the comment on it.

I have tried starting the server and loading the content.

Is there an extra step needed to use the where condition with firestore in react?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console when you uncomment it?

Comment: Thanks @wobsoriano - i thought the index was only required where there were 2 where conditions in a query. the orderBy must be counted as one of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely (as user wobsoriano hinted at in a comment) you are getting an error message in the console output about needing to define a composite index for the two fields used in this query: `sharing` and `title`.

If you're having a hard time find the error message, you can also put a `try... catch` around the query and log it somewhere where you can more easily find it.

Either way: in that error message you'll find a link that takes you directly to the Firestore console page to create the index. All fields will be prepopulated, so all you have to do is click the link, create the index, and wait a few minutes for it to complete.

Comment: Yes - I saw the error but I thought that must be buggy. I just read a blog describing the need for the index where there were 2+ where conditions. I didn't expect the orderBy would be treated as a where. Thank you.